# Display Alerts in Excel from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am opening an excel workbook from excel and delete a sheet inside. I want to do this without the message from Excel:
"Excel will permanently delete this sheet, do you want to continue"
However I cannot make the "DisplayAlerts = False" work correctly.

```
Public Sub xportQuery()

Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

Dim PathDaily, FileName As String
PathDaily = Forms!Menu!Text69
FileName = Forms!Menu!Text84

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(PathDaily & FileName)
appExcel.Visible = True
'Set appExcel = Nothing
Set myWorkbook = Nothing

appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Sheety").Delete
appExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Writing it this way I get a "Subscript out of range" on the `Sheets("Sheety").delete`
If I take of the two DisplayAlerts lines, the code works but with the alert.

How do I write my code correctly to work without any alert message?

Note: DoCmd.SetWarnings didn t work either as the message is displayed in Excel

Comment: What happens if you replace `Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Sheety").Delete` with `myWorkbook.Sheets("Sheety").Delete`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To Sam's Comment:

it works either by changing

```
Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Sheety").Delete
```

into

```
myWorkbook.Sheets("Sheety").Delete
```

or

```
AppExcel.Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Sheety").Delete
```

However the rest of the macro can still use Workbooks(Filename) without the "AppExcel." Reference

Comment: *However the rest of the macro can still use Workbooks(Filename) without the "AppExcel." Reference* -- even if it seems to work, you should never do this. It can lead to strange behavior (as you have seen), or Excel processes not closing down if you do `appExcel.Quit`